# Maximum amperage as a function of Number of conductors

Tags: wiring, gauge

When you push too much amperage through a wire, the wire overheats and melts the insulation.  12/2 romex and 12/3 romex both use 12 gauge wire and are both rated at 20 amps (600V).  When used with a 3-way light switch, however, the power is flowing on both the black and red conductors in 12/3 cable.  To me this suggests that more heat should be generated within the outer casing of the cable for the same amperage.

See: https://assets.southwire.com/ImConvServlet/imconv/cc9ee246a3e9a87c880b862c8b599829546d060e/origin?assetDescr=Romex%20Brand%20SIMpull%20Indoor%20Wire%20Copper%20NM-B%20Cable

So it seems like:

1. there is some limitation on 12/3 vs 12/2 that I'm not aware of -or-
2. there is some difference in construction of 12/3 vs 12/2 that I'm not aware of -or-
3. I'm confused about the physics here.

Can someone clarify please?

---

Edit:  Consider the following picture:
[image]

For the switch on the right, the power is coming down the wire on the red or white-with-black-stripe, and returning on the black wire, thus taking two passes through the cable.

Comment: "3." Current flows on one traveler at a time, "black OR red".

Comment: The wires might be rated at 20 amps each, but the circuit itself can only have 20 amps total, not 20 amps each wire.

Comment: Please see the picture I just posted.  This circuit has 20 amps total, with current flow through the cable on the right twice.

Comment: Even a circuit carrying current in more than one wire, it still can only equal 20 amps.  So 10A plus 10A equals 20A maximum, not 20A plus 20A.

Comment: This is not true.  If you look at the figure above, 20A down to the switch on the right (on red or white), and 20A back from the switch on the right (on black).

Comment: Christopher, you are concerned that the cable is "actually" carrying twice the rated current. Don't be. The cable is rated for  20 A coming and going even though the heat generated is the same that would be generated if the same cable were carrying 40 A by *two wires each carrying 20 A in the same direction*.   A properly connected circuit always has the comin' n goin' currents in the same cable so that the total current (respecting the sign) is zero. This is to reduce to zero the magnetic field strength around the cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 3-ways have no color codes

> When used with a 3-way light switch, however, the power is flowing on both the black and red conductors in 12/3 cable.

OK first, there are no standardized colors in 3-way circuits.  There are at least 5 different ways to lay out a 3-way circuit, and that may demand using almost any color for any wire function. So when you say "red and black" that doesn't mean anything.

Current flows in loops.  And thanks to NEC 300.3, the currents in any cable need to be equal and opposite.  So in any given 3-way circuit, you have 2 conductors that are flowing normal current, and one that is idle.  Thus a 12/3 in that service doesn't make any more heat than a 12/2.

### Thermal factors when current-splitting

It works out even better in split control or  *multi-wire branch circuits*, where one wire carries 100% current and the other 2 wires split the return current. **Heat generated is *the square of* current.** So 2 wires splitting 20A current will always make less heat (together) than 1 wire carrying 20A current.

If A + B = C then A<sup>2</sup> + B<sup>2</sup> <= C<sup>2</sup>.

Plug in a few numbers and try it!

In fact, this is the only thing that ever happens when dealing with *single-phase* or *split single-phase* power (an example of the latter is North American 120V/240V).  Therefore thermally, any circuit counts as 2 wires for thermal calculations (e.g. NEC 310.15(B)(3)(A)).

### Three-phase, though...

However when dealing with 3-phase power, your thermal concerns re: 12/3 cable become real.  If you use 12/3 to power a motor that requires 208V "delta" power, then indeed, you can have honest 20A of current on all three wires.  But 12/3 wire is in fact rated for that.

Code handles thermal calculations in 310.15.  As you can imagine it's quite a complicated section, with lots of allowances for insulation temperature, ambient temperature, number of wires bundled or in conduits, etc.

### Thermal derates come off the highest possible temperature of the wire.

Which is higher than the highest current you're actually allowed to use.  NM-B is a special case, and it is absent from the tables.  Per its Chapter 3 article, it *is limited to* the actual current in the 60C column (20A for #12) but its thermal derates are computed off the current in the 90C column (30A for #12).

So four instance you can have four  NM 12/2 cables bundled. *8 conductors calls for a 30% thermal derate*.  NM derates off the 90C figure (30A), giving 21A.  However NM can't exceed the 60C number of 20A *in any case*...  so final answer: 20A.

Even if you use a wire type with a higher thermal limit, 240.4(D) also limits current on #18-#10 wires again to the 60C figures (e.g. 20A).

Answer (score 2):

### There are still only 2 current-carrying conductors involved

What you're not grasping is that only *one* of the black and red wires ever carries current at any given time, as the switches select which traveler is the "hot" conductor for the purposes of this analysis.  As a result, Code treats the 12/3 the same as a 12/2 here, although there is no difference even if all three wires in the 12/3 *are* current-carrying conductors, as the derate for "too many wires carrying current" (*ampacity adjustment* in the NEC) doesn't start kicking in until you have *4* current-carrying conductors, and isn't significant for 15, 20, or 30A circuits until you get to **9** conductors!